Bluetooth mouse wheel erratic
Using CachyOS, an Arch derivative, a Tecknet Bluetooth mouse wheel does not work properly: it sometimes does not detect scroll movement, others it goes the wrong way, others it goes forward and immediately back. I have already checked the mouse on other devices and it works fine.
Following is a video of scrolling as usual with a wired mouse and with the bluethooth mouse. The be scrolling is the same for both, save the bluetooth i never got to the end so never scrolled up, but  its the same.
Video of scrolling
Any help would be greatly appreciated
Update: when libinput record is running, it works mostly normally

given the speed the mouse may be generating pulses (and that it works on other machines), see if you can find a way to confirm that the bluetooth on your cachyOS is performing up-to-spec. What about positioning of bluetooth endponts (PC and mouse), .... could shifting positions make a better radio signal?

you might flag your question for moderation and ask them to move it to [su] . You'll get some new eyes on your problem there. DON'T duplicate your post, someone will find it and you'll be in a whole-lotta-trouble (-;!
